# Singleton WebService (ASMX, not WCF)

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

Is there a way to define an C# ASMX WebService as singleton? Maybe in the Web.config file? Currently I'm not using WCF.

Thanks in advance

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.eu/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What is it you want to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create `Singleton` web service, because web service runs on IIS and is treated as web app and is maintained as such. Each client will share single application instance, but each of them will have own Request, Response, Session etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your web service behind a facade that is a singleton:

```cs
public static class ServiceFacade
{
    public static void ServiceOperation()
    {
        using (var service = new MyService())
        {
            service.Operation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the AppDomain of the server side (service) is created/destroy on each client request. So, even the static object has no effect then. Or?

Comment: This is incorrect. The client does not control the creation and distruction of the service's AppDomain. That's up to the host environment on the server. Web services are usually hosted by IIS and IIS will generally have one AppDomain for a long period of time (since creating AppDomains is quite costly). You can configure this in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will check if I can configure the development server of VisualStudio accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make the main data object also static and it will be shared through all the worker instances.

Comment: But the AppDomain of the server side (service) is created/destroy on each client request. So, even the static object has no effect then. Or?

Comment: I think there was possibility to configure the behavior in IIS, but I honestly do not remember. Why do you want to use the asmx in favor of WCF anyway?

Comment: I was more familiar with ASMX, but I guess I will switch to WCF now. It's more flexible anyway.

Comment: I've had some incompatibility issues when replacing old Asmx services with WCF ones. Mostly with asmx clients that are implemented in other programming languages and probably hard coded. Other than that it is a breeze.